# ¿Cómo filtrar elementos de un ArrayList?

Tags: java

Tengo un `ArrayList` con muchos elementos. Quiero que me elimine del ´ArrayList´ los elementos que no son "arbol".

Hasta ahora he realizado el siguiente código, el cual borra los elementos que no sean árboles:

```
for(int i=0;i<elementosCreados.size();i++){
           if( elementosCreados.get(i).compareTo("arbol")!=0){
                elementosCreados.remove(i);
            }
}
```

¿Cómo podría recolocar los elementos del ´ArrayList´ para que no hubiese posiciones vacías?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si utilizas Java 8 o superior, la solución de [@CarlosMuñoz](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/6652/227) es la más adecuada.

Para Java 7 o inferior, lo puedes realizar utilizando `Iterator`:

```
System.out.println(elementosCreados);
Iterator<String> it = elementosCreados.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) {
    String current = it.next();
    if (!current.equals("arbol")) {
        it.remove();
    }
}
System.out.println(elementosCreados);
```

Answer (score 2):

Podrías usar `.stream()` y `.filter()` de Java 8:

```
elementosCreados = elementosCreados
    .stream()
    .filter(x -> !x.equals("arbol"))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar tan rápido. He probado con la opción que me indicaste pero no me reconoce el método stream(), ni el de collect(). ¿Por qué puede pasar esto?

Comment: Que versión de Java estas usando, streams, lambdas y collectors están disponibles desde la versión 8?, Además para la clase Collectors debes hacer `java.util.stream.Collectors`

Comment: Tenias razón, estaba utilizando una versión de java inferior, por eso no me reconocía los métodos.

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas utilizar programación funcional en versiones anteriores a Java 8 puedes utilizar [Guava](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) de Google, esta librería te permite tener un código como este:

```
@Test
public void testArrayListFilter() {

  List<String> list=new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList("perro","gato","arbol","leon"));

  Iterables.removeIf(list, new Predicate<String>() {
    @Override
    public boolean apply(String element) {
      if(element.equals("arbol")) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
  }); 

  assertThat(list.contains("arbol"),is(false));
  assertThat(list.size(),is(3));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Otra con [*Google Guava*](https://github.com/google/guava):

```java
List<String> list = Lists.newArrayList("arbol", "arbol", "casa", "auto");
List<String> filtrada = Lists.newArrayList(FluentIterable.from(list).filter(
        Predicates.not(Predicates.equalTo("arbol"))));
```

> El estilo de programación fluida nos permite encadenar juntas las llamadas a los métodos, haciendo un código más legible.<sup>1</sup>

---

*Notas*

1. Bill Bejeck, *Getting Started with Google Guava*, Packt Publishing, 2013, p. 40.

Answer (score 1):

Con JAVA 8 Tienes otra forma de hacerlo :

```
elementosCreados.removeIf(x-> !x.equals("Arbol"));
```